# Thymeleaf + Spring MVC - Thymeleaf template parsing error on using checkbox input

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm following this tutorial which uses Spring MVC, Spring Boot and Thymeleaf as the view. I'm getting a Template Parsing Error when I use a **checkbox input** on the HTML form, and strangely, when I remove the checkbox input, everything works well.

Here is the HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <style>
       h1,h2 {
           color: rebeccapurple;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is home page</h1>

<h2>Enter data below</h2>
<form action="/create" method="post" th:object="${userData}">
    <p><label>
        Full Name<input type="text" th:field="${userData.fullName}" />
    </label></p>

    <p><label>
        Age <input type="text" th:field="${userData.age}" />
    </label></p>


    <p><label>
        Employed? <input type="checkbox" th:field="${userData.isEmployed}"/>
    </label></p>

    <p> Gender
        <label>
            Male
            <input type="radio" th:field="${userData.gender}" th:value="Male"/>
        </label>
        <label>
            Female
            <input type="radio" th:field="${userData.gender}" th:value="Female"/>
        </label>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller class -

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String showHomeForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userData", new User());
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processHomeForm(User user) {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

Here is the domain (User) class -

```
public class User {
    // these fields were private initially...
    public String fullName;
    public String age;
    public boolean isEmployed;
    public String gender;

    public User() {
        System.out.println("User default constructor");
    }

    public User(String fullName, String age, boolean isEmployed, String gender) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.age = age;
        this.isEmployed = isEmployed;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean isEmployed() {
        return isEmployed;
    }

    public void setEmployed(boolean employed) {
        isEmployed = employed;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the error and the stacktrace -

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri May 22 11:58:42 EDT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 27, col 42)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 27, col 42)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'isEmployed' of bean class [com.jrp.springdemo.domain.User]: Bean property 'isEmployed' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:258)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    ... 63 more
```

The stacktrace includes a message about the `isEmployed` field of the `User` class being an invalid property -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'isEmployed' of bean class [com.jrp.springdemo.domain.User]: Bean property 'isEmployed' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

I think this is what is causing the template parsing error, but I have it exactly the way its shown in the tutorial.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `th:field` should `employed` rather than `isEmployed`.

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="${userData.employed}" />
```

The relevant error from your stack tracec:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'isEmployed' of bean class
>   [com.jrp.springdemo.domain.User]: Bean property 'isEmployed' is not
>   readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the
>   getter match the parameter type of the setter?

For boolean values, `employed` checks for getter `isEmployed()` and setter `setEmployed(...)`.  For any other types `employed` would check for getter `getEmployed()` and setter `setEmployed(...)`.  Since you tried to use `isEmployed` that means that Thymeleaf was looking for `isIsEmployed()` or `getIsEmployed()`.

Comment: Thank You so much. The tutorial also used `employed` as the field name, but I thought it's better to use `isEmployed` as it was a boolean field. Didn't know the getter methods look for a specific name.