# ThymeLeaf th:with object property -> how does it fetch properties?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have an Owner object that inherits a BaseEntity that has method isNew() that checks if this.id==null;
In thymeleaf template, I have th:with="text=${owner['new']} ? 'Add Owner' : 'Update Owner'"

Can someone please explain how thymeleaf links the isNew() method with the ['new'] property of Owner?
I'm just confused b/c there is no explicit 'new' property but is just a method.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61960624/12567365) - which is for a different question, but happens to provide an answer to your question. More generally, the process process follows established [JavaBean naming conventions](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm).

Comment: ok got it, Spring will automatically check for isNew() or getNew() methods in the class and since it is there in the BaseEntity then it is called. thanks for the answer!